# Bad data in User Profile DB from BAD AD

Tags: user-profile

I dont want to re-create UPS because it has bad data due to bad data in AD. We have a new AD with good data. Is there a way to truncate all the users from User profile DB to start over the population?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "new" AD.  If it's the same domain and you cleaned it up then the changes should just sync over like @waqassarwar has said.  If it's a new domain - you need to do more than just cleanup profiles for it work.  But to answer your question - yes you can delete the profiles.  A quick search and here is a ready made script Courtesy of TechNet

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Delete-all-User-Profiles-fa4e1428

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added 
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) { 
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" 
} 


$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://skvkfm-it01/");  
$ServiceContext = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($site);  

#Get UserProfileManager from the My Site Host Site context 
$ProfileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)    
$AllProfiles = $ProfileManager.GetEnumerator()  

foreach($profile in $AllProfiles)  
{  
    $DisplayName = $profile.DisplayName  
    $AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value  

    #Do not delete setup (admin) account from user profiles. Please enter the account name below 
    if($AccountName -ne "Domain\MySiteSVApp") 
    { 
        $ProfileManager.RemoveUserProfile($AccountName); 
        write-host "Profile for account ", $AccountName, " has been deleted" 
    } 

}  
write-host "Finished." 
$site.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of Bad data you are talking about.

But typically when you run a Full Sync of the User Profile Services followed by Incermental Sync, it automatically remove the bad data / users.

may be you can try to place some filter.